# linux + how to Kill stuck program after few seconds

Tags: linux

I execute the following binary file on my linux/Solaris system ( in order to get system info )

```
      /usr/sbin/diag
```

After diag command running,I get some lines on screen , but its stuck , and I not get the Linux/Solaris prompt (diag program not return exe code 0 or 1 because its stuck -:( )

( the only way to exit prom diag is to perform CNTL – C )

my question:  if there are some ways to kill the diag binary program after ~5 second

For example

```
   /usr/sbin/diag &      ( the lines runs on screen but diag stuck , need to CNTRL-C )
   Wait ~5 
   Kill the /usr/sbin/diag process (&!)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your shell has job control disabled.

Check that you

- are running on a terminal
- are starting the shell in interactive mode

See

> [Shells offer features geared specifically for interactive use rather than to augment the programming language. These interactive features include job control, command line editing, command history and aliases. Each of these features is described in this manual.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#What-is-a-shell_003f)

And

- [Job Control](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control)

Comment: That's some nice crystal-ball work -- I haven't seen a shell without job control in so long it's easy to forget they even exist.

Answer (score 2):

```
/usr/sbin/diag & # run diag in background
pid=$! # set last run command's process id into pid var
sleep 5s # wait 5 seconds
kill -9 $pid # kill that pid
```

Comment: /usr/sbin/diag & -> this not help the diag program still stuck and I only can get out with contl - c

Comment: you mean to add your procedure in to bash script?

Comment: No, that is a bash script... all bash scripts have to have a shebang in the front of them. Just write a shebang and paste that in and run it

Answer (score 1):

See the timeout command, you should install it, then run

```
timeout 60 command_line
```

for a 60 secondes timeout. It's safe and smart.

Comment: I Cant install the time out because we cant make any install steps on this system ,  this linux OS is critical server and the customer (cellular company) not want to install any additional package on the system

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

```
/usr/sbin/diag &
sleep 5 ; kill $!
```

The `bash(1)` variable `$!` refers to the pid of the most recently executed backgrounded command. So, if you cannot place `diag` into the background, then this won't work for you.

Comment: /usr/sbin/diag & -> this not help the diag program still stuck and I only can get out with contl - c

Answer (score 0):

```
timelimit 60 command_line args
```

Is also a way to do this. It is part of the netpipes package.